# Setting a proxy for an nginx upstream server

Tags: nginx, proxy

Is it possible for an upstream directive to specify an HTTP proxy to route these requests through? Something along the lines of:

```
upstream external {
    server example.com;
    proxy localhost:3128;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no directive for passing ProxyPass through a forward proxy, but you can trick nginx in doing so:

- You configure your forward proxy to function as a transparant proxy (which means this solution will only work for HTTP)
- You add your destination (external) to your /etc/hosts so that it points to the IP of your forward proxy (localhost)